# Like the .assoc method when working with multidimensional arrays in Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, multidimensional-array

I'm in a pickle with multidimensional arrays. I'm looking for an easy way to do the following:

I have a multidimensional array like this:

multi_a = [[20, "John"], ["27", "Michael"], [37, "Annie"], [20, "James"], [98, "Roberta"], [20, "Andrea"]]

I want to return all

I know that multi_a.assoc(20) will return [20, "John"]

I want it to return [[20, "John"], [20, "James"], [20, "Andrea"]

Thanks guys

p.s there is a valid reason I haven't turned it into a hash, it's to do with ranking...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`assoc` will return the first one that matches or nil. You can write a small block to handle this logic for you. This should work `multi_a.select { |a| a.include? 20 }`

For example:

```
multi_a = [[20, "John"], ["27", "Michael"], [37, "Annie"], [20, "James"], [98, "Roberta"], [20, "Andrea"]]
multi_a.select { |a| a.include? 20 }

=> [[20, "John"], [20, "James"], [20, "Andrea"]]
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop through the whole array to find all of the matches. You are just getting the first match.

From ruby-doc.org, regarding "assoc":

> Searches through an array whose elements are also arrays comparing obj
>   with the first element of each contained array using obj.==.
>
> **Returns the first contained array that matches** (that is, the first
>   associated array), or nil if no match is found.

Taken from [this link](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html).